# Multiple file uploads with php

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm trying to upload two files with one form post however my form will only upload the first file and doesn't iterate over the 2nd file and upload. Any idea why? The code I'm using is below.

```
<?php

$upload = $_POST['upload'];
$enteredPassword = $_POST['password'];
$uploadedFiles = $_FILES;
$password = "************";

// Where the file is going to be placed 
$target_path = "";

//interger count
$i = 0;

//upload the files
if ($upload == true && $enteredPassword == $password) {
foreach($uploadedFiles as $uploadedFile) {
    $target_path = $target_path . $uploadedFile['name'][$i]; 

    if(move_uploaded_file($uploadedFile['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) {
        echo "<p>The file ".  $uploadedFile['name'][$i]. 
        " has been uploaded.</p>";
    } else{
        echo "<p>There was an error uploading the {$uploadedfile['name']}, please try again!</p>";
    }
    $i++;
}
}
?>

<ul>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="true" />
    <li>Choose a file to upload:</li>
    <li><input name="userfile[]" type="file" size="40" /></li>
    <li><input name="userfile[]" type="file" size="40" /></li>
    <li>Enter password for file upload:</li>
    <li><input name="password" type="password" size="40" /></li>
    <li><input type="submit" value="Upload File" /></li>
</form>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior is expected because there is only one element in your $_FILES array which is $_FILES["userfile"]. You can try something like this to achieve what you want:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $upload = $_POST['upload'];
    $enteredPassword = $_POST['password'];
    $uploadedFiles = $_FILES["userfile"];
    $password = "12345";

    // Where the file is going to be placed 
    $base_path = "upload/";

    //upload the files
    if ($upload == true && $enteredPassword == $password) {
        foreach(array_combine($uploadedFiles["name"], $uploadedFiles["tmp_name"]) as $name => $tmp_name) {
            $target_path = $base_path .$name; 

            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $target_path)) {
                echo "<p>The file ".  $name." has been uploaded.</p>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<p>There was an error uploading the {$name}, please try again!</p>";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>

<ul>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="true" />
    <li>Choose a file to upload:</li>
    <li><input name="userfile[]" type="file" /></li>
    <li><input name="userfile[]" type="file" /></li>
    <li>Enter password for file upload:</li>
    <li><input name="password" type="password" size="40" /></li>
    <li><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload File" /></li>
</form>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like you can use this plugin for multiple image upload. its works great for me ...http://www.plupload.com/example_queuewidget.php

Answer (score 0):

Try, uploadify
It's good for multiple uploads with great api and callback.
 http://www.uploadify.com/